# Convert audio to text

Tags: audio, software-rec, speech-recognition

I heard about existence of some speech recognition systems, and it seems I need one of those. Basically, I have an audio file with speech (only one person is speaking most of the time), and I want to get a transcript of the speech.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: I don't think there's open-source voice-recognition engine available

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_speech_recognition_software has several open source ones

Answer (score 2):

You could give [`Palaver`](https://github.com/JamezQ/Palaver#palaver-speech-recognition) a try. Recently released and still beta but quite OK.
Here is [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfrQrjH3AGw) showing some of the features, including `dictation mode`.